# semantic UI Icons are not loading in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, semantic-ui

I have added semantic in my rails 6 app through yarn package manager by following the way written in [this repo](https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass#ruby-on-rails-version-6-with-webpacker) this is my envirnoment.js file code

```
    const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    
    environment.plugins.append(
      'Provide',
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
      })
    )
    
    module.exports = environment
```

This is my application.js file code

```
 

    import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
    import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
    import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
    import "channels"
    import '@doabit/semantic-ui-sass'
    
    
    Rails.start()
    Turbolinks.start()
    ActiveStorage.start()
```

and this is the code of my custom css file

```
@import '@doabit/semantic-ui-sass/src/scss/semantic-ui.scss';
```

now when I add classes for icons. icons are not shown on screen. everything else is working fine except icons.it is showing this error in console
[image]
I have checked in my node modules this file is present in this directory
[image]